# How do you choose an appropriate time series regression model?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, growth-model

I am working on a research proposal where I want to test the effect of different macroeconomic variables (i.e. government spending, FDI, trade openness, international GDP growth, etc.) on the GDP growth of a particular country. I am gathering quarterly data for each of these variables over a ~25 year period. At the end of the analysis I'd like to be able to say that an x macroeconomic variable had a z% (positive/negative) impact on GDP growth over the time period studied. I am not trying to forecast anything, I just want to be able to explain the historical GDP growth of the country based on relevant macroeconomic variables.

I have extensive knowledge of linear regressions through OLS but this is my first time learning about time series regression. I am teaching myself about time series through Stock and Watson's "Introduction to Econometrics." I've also researched a lot of economics papers, but there doesn't seem to be one set model that is used in GDP growth analyses (I've seen SUR, VAR, VECM, etc.).

I am trying to figure out the appropriate econometric model to use for my analysis. According to the book, a big part of time series is using an autoregression, but the book includes past values of the dependent variable as regressors in their example. For my research, I don't care about the effects of past GDP, I only care about the effects of the other variables. Would it be appropriate to build a model that does not include lagged GDP as independent variables? Is there a particular model that is most often used in these types of cases? I know there are other considerations like endogeneity of variables, stationarity, etc. that must be checked, but right now my main issue is just coming up with the correct model in the first place. Any ideas or explanations would be much appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you start with VAR. It is widely known that you should expect feedback between variables when estimating macroeconomic models with time series. Also, checking cross impacts with it is quiet straightforward using impulse response functions. [This](https://bookdown.org/ccolonescu/RPoE4/vec-and-var-models.html) material presents a nice walkthrough using R. You should of course consider that there might exist some cointegration in your model (case in which VECM would suit you better), but starting with the basics always help understand the benefits of more complex methodologies.